# Development phase: php keeps displaying images that have been deleted

Tags: php, wamp

I am in the development phase of my project. I am using WAMP, Dreamweaver, and IE9. Recently I changed the color of one of the image in my source folder. The problem is that when calling a php page via WAMP the image displayed is the old one (which does not exist anymore(?)) not the new one. It only happens with php pages. It works fine with html pages.

So I believe the problem is not coming from Dreamweaver or IE9. It comes from WAMP. Looks like my old image is saved somewhere (but where?) and for some strange reasons WAMP is loading it instead of the new image.

Has anyone of you met this problem before? How to solve that? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried clearing your browser cache?

Comment: change your browser and your problem will be solved.It's cache problem try to clean it

Answer (score 0):

Websites will store images in cache once it has loaded it from your website. This is to avoid redownloading a file that hasn't changed. Sometimes, however, the files have changed and the browser is still serving the cached version. There are a few ways to get rid of this.

1. Clear your cache
2. Set you browser to not cache images
3. Some browsers will offer "private browsing". Not only will this not store things like cookies and history, but it will also not cache images. At least, it will only cache them until the private browsing window is closed.
4. Add a querystring to any file you want to serve with a timestamp like `<link href="styles.css?version=213948183214 />`. This is typically for development purposes, though. You wouldn't want to do this in production unless it is essential.
5. Some browsers offer a "hard-refresh" like Chrome and Firefox. If you hold shift while reloading, it will refresh all served files with a fresh version.
6. Open the page in a new browser